# Restrict file sharing to just view a (text) file in browser, but not print or copy

Tags: permissions, file-sharing

GDrive makes it possible to share a text file with a permission to view it online (GUI mode, in the browser), but without permissions to download, print or copy text from the file.

Can a text file (plain or formatted) be shared online with the permissions and restrictions just mentioned, without using GDrive? That is, by using general sharing tools, such as ftp or sync?

I'm using a desktop with Xubuntu 4.15.0-106-generic.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Is this a server or a desktop? Are you asking only about text based tools or GUI? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1251675/edit) and add all the new details **to your question**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Question edited.

Comment: I suppose one can run a web server that restricts copying of text and display the text as a webpage. However, this does not sound like a Ubuntu specific problem. You may get better answers if you ask this question in [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957443/prevent-copying-text-in-web-page).

Comment: I hadn't thought about the server solution (I've never set up one), but perhaps would be the way to achieve the customization I'm asking about. Besides, I think it's http sharing what I actually need. Thanks for your help!